# Stretch flex parent to (variable) children width in scrollable container

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

Here's what I have (from outer to inner):

1. A parent element with `overflow: scroll` and fixed width.
2. A vertical list of elements with variable width
3. List items have `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`
4. Inside each list item there is an icon and a label side by side horizontally

I want the list items to take as much width as they need to container their *flexed* children, as the root parent is scrollable. I can make the icon and label take as much width as they need with `flex-shrink: 0`.

Problem is: **List items (#3 in the list above) have their width limited to the width of the scrollable parent container, instead of their children.**

This is bad because list items have padding and a colored background. **[Here is an example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/roygyp?editors=1100#0)**. Scroll horizontally where it says "Lorem ipsum" to see what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: .list {
  display: inline-grid;
} is fine too, but with a little bit less browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make `list` an `inline-block` element and it won't get limited by its parent width and will expand to fit the longest item:

```css
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f5;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.list {
  display:inline-block;
}

.item-container {
  padding: 0 16px;
  background: #222225;
  color: #e1e1e8;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.label {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"> 
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet yata yata yata</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="label">Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Fan fact, though, if you remove `white-space: nowrap` from the label the whole thing falls apart, even though the text stays on one line due to `flex-shrink: 0`. Can there be a logical explanation for that? :)

Comment: @treznik yes, it's somehow tricky, but the text is now overflowing the container. when you set `white-space:nowrap` the container know that the text will not wrap so he will consider the width of the text to calculate its width thus the good behavior. Now without whitespace the text is supposed to wrap so the calculation will be based on the wrap BUT when you add flex-shrink:0 you will make the element behave differently and will overflow. In other words, white-space is considered from the start to have everything good but flex-shrink is considered later to scramble things.